# Adding derived classes to a Binding Source of a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, model-view-controller

Using MVC Pattern in WinForms with C#

Three business object - an abstract LibraryItem Class ,a Book class and a journal class , both derives from LibraryItem

```
//LibraryItem Class
public abstract class LibraryItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    private static int _nextCallNum = 1000;

    public int CallNum { get; private set; }

    public int NumCopies { get; set; }
}

//Journal Class
 public class Journal : LibraryItem
{
    public int Vol { get; set; }
}

//Book Class
 public class Book : LibraryItem
{
    public string Author { get; set; }
}


//LibraryController Class 
  public class LibrayController
{

    //a List that can hold both books and journals
    private List<LibraryItem> items;

     //adds a book object to items
     public void AddBookItem(string title, int numCopies , string author) {.....}

      //adds a journal object to items
     public void AddJournal(string title, int vol, int numCopies){}

      //returns a List contaning books and journals to the View
      public List<LibraryItem> GetAllItems()
    {
        return items;
    }
}
```

In Win Forms , using a DataGridView to display list of LibraryItems

```
dataGridViewItems.DataSource = null;

booksbindingSource = new BindingSource();

 foreach (LibraryItem anitem in controller.GetAllItems())
        {

            LibraryItem aLibraryItem = (LibraryItem) anitem;

            booksbindingSource.Add(aLibraryItem);
        }

dataGridViewItems.DataSource = booksbindingSource;
```

When adding a book after journal, or a journal after book to the binding source, I get *InvalidOperationException Objects added to a BindingSource's list must all be of the same type*.

The description is self-explanatory. I need a way to display LibraryItems in a datagrid than can be both books and journals. I only need to display the base class properties(Title, CallNum and NumCopies of LibraryItem) in the datagrid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `DataSource` property of `BindingSource` has not already been set, then the first object added to the list defines the type for the list, and then all items that you want to add to the list, should be of the type of first object, because the internal list must contain homogeneous types as mentioned in [documentations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.add(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2).

Instead of adding items to `BindingSource` using `Add` method, set its `DataSource` property to the list which you get from controller:

```
var bs = new BindingSource();
var list = controller.GetAllItems();
bs.DataSource = list;
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

**Note**

To solve the problem, its enough and recommended to use above method, but to see the affect of setting `DataSource`, you can set `DataSource` property to `typeof(LibraryItem)` and you will see it also works as expected:

```
bs.DataSource = typeof(LibraryItem);
foreach (var item in list)
{
    bs.Add(item);
}
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: While you have the choice of not using a `BindingSource`, I suppose you want to use a `BindingSource`, so the answer solves the problem when using `BindingSource`. If you don't use a `BindingSource` you can simply set the `DataSource` of your `DataGridView` to your list.

Comment: Yes. Made it simple by setting `DataSource` of the `DataGridView` directly to the list without using a `BindingSource`.

Comment: Use a System.ComponentModel.BindingList so the list informs the DataGridView that an item was added etc.