# Bind UI controls to objects of derived types

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list of `Doctors`, `Teachers` and `Drivers`, all of them are derived from `Individual`.
Depending on what person the cursor is at, I'd like to display profession-specific properties.
My idea was to have all those guys in a `BindingList<Individual>` which was a datasource for `IndividualsBindingSource`.
On the `IndividualsBindingSource.CurrentChanged` event I would display a profession-specific panel and create `Bindings` for profession-specific controls on the fly so when being on a driver then his driver license is displayed etc.

But in the body of the `CurrentChanged` event this line gives runtime error:

```
tbLicense.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", IndividualsBindingSource, "DriverLicense", true));
```

what probably means that it cannot bind control to the `DriverLicense` property of underlying datasource because the datasource is of base type `Individual`.

Q1: Is there a way to bind UI controls to inherited objects properties while having all objects in a `BindingList<base type>`?
Q2: If not then what is the best practice for displaying object-specific controls allowing 2-way binding?

Comment: Can you create bindingsources for the derived types (design time or run time) and "chain" these to the base bindingsource in some way when CurrentChanged fires. Use explicit casting somewhere? Did you check all different constructors of Binding? I can't give you a direct answer but maybe some direction in which to seek.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36756849/468910

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, it was too easy...
Instead of binding to the list

```
tbLicense.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", IndividualsBindingSource, "DriverLicense", true));
```

I had to bind to specific object

```
tbLicense.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", IndividualsBindingSource.Current, "DriverLicense", true));
```